# Unity3D [Android] Firebase Remote Config Error

Tags: unity3d, firebase, config, unity3d-android

Есть скрипт, который сверяет версию клиента с сервером, на пк код работает отлично, но при сборке на Android данные попросту не приходят. Сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;



public class RemoteConfig : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject nextbutton;

    public GameObject basicbutton;

    [SerializeField]
    private double actualVersion;
    private string stringVersion;
    [SerializeField]
    private double appVersion;

    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
                InitializeFirebase();
            } else {
                Debug.LogError(
                    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    void InitializeFirebase() {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> defaults =
            new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        defaults.Add("config_test_string", "default local string");
        defaults.Add("config_test_int", 1);
        defaults.Add("config_test_float", 1.0);
        defaults.Add("config_test_bool", false);

        Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.SetDefaults(defaults);
        Debug.Log("Remote config ready!");
        FetchFireBase();
    }
    public void FetchFireBase() {
        FetchDataAsync();
    }
    public void ShowData() {

            Debug.Log("Server version: " + Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("version").StringValue);
            Debug.Log("Client version: " + appVersion);
            stringVersion = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("version").StringValue;
            double.TryParse(stringVersion, out actualVersion);
            if (actualVersion > appVersion)
            {
                Debug.Log("Version: ERROR!");
                basicbutton.SetActive(false);
                nextbutton.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Version: OK!");
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
            }

    }
    public void OnButtonExitPressed()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
    public Task FetchDataAsync() {
        Debug.Log("Fetching data...");

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task fetchTask = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.FetchAsync(
            TimeSpan.Zero);
        return fetchTask.ContinueWith(FetchComplete);

    }

    void FetchComplete(Task fetchTask) {
        if (fetchTask.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.Log("Fetch canceled.");
        } else if (fetchTask.IsFaulted) {
            Debug.Log("Fetch encountered an error.");
        } else if (fetchTask.IsCompleted) {
            Debug.Log("Fetch completed successfully!");
        }

        var info = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.Info;
        switch (info.LastFetchStatus) {
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Success:
                Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.ActivateFetched();
                Debug.Log(String.Format("Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time {0}).",
                    info.FetchTime));
                break;
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Failure:
                switch (info.LastFetchFailureReason) {
                    case Firebase.RemoteConfig.FetchFailureReason.Error:
                        Debug.Log("Fetch failed for unknown reason");
                        break;
                    case Firebase.RemoteConfig.FetchFailureReason.Throttled:
                        Debug.Log("Fetch throttled until " + info.ThrottledEndTime);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Pending:
                Debug.Log("Latest Fetch call still pending.");
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась отладкой. На пк после целого числа ставилась запятая, а в андроиде точка. Соответственно поэтому и не могли версии сходиться.